# Prove an estimator

Tags: algorithms, graphs, probabilistic-algorithms

Consider an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ representing the social network of friendship/trust between students. We would like to form teams of three students that know each other. The question is to decide whether the network allows for enough such teams, without checking all the triples of graph $G$. For this reason, we use random sampling to design an efficient estimator of the number of connected triples. We partition the set of node triples into four sets $T_0,T_1,T_2$, and $T_3$. A node triple $v_1,v_2,v_3$ belongs to:

$T_0$ iff no edge exists between the nodes $v_1,v_2,$ and $v_3$,

$T_1$ iff exactly one of the edges $(v_1,v_2), (v_2,v_3)$, and $(v_3,v_1)$ exists,

$T_2$ iff exactly two of the edges $(v_1,v_2), (v_2,v_3)$, and $(v_3,v_1)$ exist,

$T_3$ iff all of the edges $(v_1,v_2), (v_2,v_3)$, and $(v_3,v_1)$ exist.

$|T_3|$ denotes the number of connected triples in the graph that is the quantity we need to estimate. Consider the following algorithm:

• Sample an edge $e=(a,b)$ uniformly chosen from $E$

• Choose a node $v$ uniformly from $V-\{a,b\}$

• if $(a,v)∈ E$ and $(b,v)∈ E$ then $x=1$, else $x=0$

Let $x_1, x_2, . . . ,x_s$ be the outcomes of $s$ independent executions of the algorithm. How can I show that $$ \frac{1 
        }{s}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{s} x_i \frac{|E|(|V |−2))}{3}
\right) $$
is an estimator of $|T_3|$?

Comment: I believe it is an estimator by definition since any function of the observed data can be used as an estimate for $|T_3|$ (although it is not guaranteed to be a *good* estimate). Are you interested in showing that your estimator has nice properties, e.g. is consistent or unbiased?

Comment: i need to prove that my result is an estimator of |T3|